# DjangoTables2 Add column from another model

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have DjangoTable for this model:

```
class Mark(models.Model)
    id_mark = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Id запису')
    id_student = models.ForeignKey(Student, blank=False, null=False, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Студент')
    id_subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, blank=False, null=False, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Предмет')
    mark = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=5, blank=False, null=False, default=None, verbose_name='Оцінка')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Оцінка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Оцінки'

    def __str__(self):
       return "{} {} {}".format(self.id_student, self.id_subject, self.mark)
```

Table:

```
class Mark_Table(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
         model = Mark
         exclude = ('id_mark',)
         attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
```

I want to add column with values from this model:

```
class Subject(models.Model)
    id_subject = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Id предмету')
    id_teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, blank=False, null=False, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Вчитель')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=False, default=None, verbose_name='Назва предмету')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Предмет'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Предмети'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

Now I have fields Student Subject Mark, I want to add filed id_teacher from another model, and relationship must remain.

Comment: Tested it, it add new column with name id_subject__id_teacher, but there is no data in it, just ' — '

Comment: Same, new empty column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add foreign key value in table using `table.Coulmn()` and specifying `accessor`
like below:

```
id_teacher = tables.Column(accessor='id_subject.id_teacher')
```

So your `Mark_Table` will look like:

```
class Mark_Table(tables.Table):
    # Define all the custom fields here including any override or adding other fields and include it in fields in meta class
    id_teacher = tables.Column(accessor='id_subject.id_teacher')

    class Meta:
         model = Mark
         fields = ['mark', 'id_teacher']  # specify all the fields you want to display here
         attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
```

Read more about adding custom field at [docs](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html)